# High charts logarithmic scale?

Tags: highcharts

I have tried setting

```
pointStart: 1
```

for each data series but I have three data series and cannot figure out how to scale the entire chart logarithmicly?

Fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/EwpWh/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `min:0` from yAxis and set `type:'logarithmic'`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/EwpWh/4/

Comment: QQ: Is there way to separate the upper two series a bit more?  A and C are pretty somewhat collapsed together.

Comment: Nope, only by changing y-values. However, you always can use shared tooltip which will display values for all points, see [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared).